# Get response headers after backbone fetch is complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I need to read response headers in an Ajax request made by backbone.js fetch method. is there any way to read headers if I override the fetch method:

```
var PageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: 'http://localhost/cms?_mn=Mod_Admin&_mf=getAllPages',

    model: PageModel,

    fetch: function (options) {
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        // The above line of code works and fetch the dataset 
        // BUT how i can read the response headers at this point
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use "success" callback to get the xhr object, so you will have an ability to get all the response headers:

```
collection.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        options.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(); // To get all the headers
        options.xhr.getResponseHeader('header_name'); // To get just one needed header
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The Backbone [`fetch()` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) returns a [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). You can call `done()` on this object to add a callback that will be invoked when the request is complete. Then use the `getResponseHeader()` method on the same `jqXHR` object to get the value of the header that you're interested in, or call `getAllResponseHeaders()` to get all headers.

So in your override of the `fetch()` method you can do something like this:

```
var jqXHR = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
jqXHR.done(function() {
    // Get all headers:
    console.log('All headers:', jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    // Or get a specific header:
    console.log('Content-Length:', jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
});
```

Comment: i get an error while running your code. "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'done'". The jqXHR has no method done.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Have you overridden the `sync()` method as well? See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/alexryd/u97wa/

Comment: oops! I switched to version 1.10.2 and now its working fine. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

take look at my implementation and how I used [parse function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse)

```
var CustomPageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CustomPage,
    url: '/pb/editor/pages',
    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        this.paginationInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination-Info'));
        return resp.items;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i found out a nicer way:
the collection fires a  "parse" function, when coming back from the server
[BakcboneJs - collection Parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse)

```
parse:function(a,b,c){      
    console.log("a",a);
    console.log("b",b);
    console.log("c",c);
},
```

our buddy is at b :)